# div alignment issue with float left

Tags: html, css

In the below picture the first 3 divs are aligned perfectly but in second row the div 'Residential property investment' starts from further right where as it should start from left.

[image]

The div float is set to left which is fine. One thing I noticed that is if I shorten the 1st row column 2 text from "Letting and Property Management" to only "letting and Property" then it works fine.

I can't figure out if it a word wrap problem or floating issue.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent that when you use floats is to use a common fixed height for all floated elements.

As another solution, you could add "display: flex;" and "flex-wrap: wrap" to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the height of every div.

And

Each row need to give **clear:both** CSS property.